# How to get keycloak users based on their effective roles

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak, keycloak-services

I am using keycloak-admin-client 13.0.0 in my Spring Boot Application. I can get all the users from KeyCloak. How to get keycloak users based on their effective roles.

[image]

Comment: There is a feature request for this https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-1902. Not sure it is available now, can't find in api documentation https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/5.0/rest-api/index.html#_users_resource